# Passing multiple parameters to shell script and parsing them

Tags: bash, do-while, getopt

I am trying to run the following program, I need to pass multiple options to get the command to be executed. Here for example: I am giving the inputs

```
/test.sh -s -n
```

script **test.sh**:

```
#! /bin/bash
#set -x
while [ $# -gt 0 ]
 do
    case $1 in
    -s) service=$2
    shift
    ;;
    -n) node=$3
     command
    break
     ;;
   *) echo "Invalid Argument"
    break
    ;;
 esac
 done
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Answer (score 4):

Using the `getopts` built-in command in *bash*:

```
#!/bin/bash

service="default"
node="default"

while getopts 's:n:' opt; do
    case $opt in
        s)  service="$OPTARG" ;;
        n)  node="$OPTARG"    ;;
        *)  exit 1            ;;
    esac
done

echo "service = '${service}'"
echo "node    = '${node}'"
```

Testing it:

```
$ ./test.sh
service = 'default'
node    = 'default'

$ ./test.sh -s hello -n world
service = 'hello'
node    = 'world'

$ ./test.sh -n world -s hello
service = 'hello'
node    = 'world'

$ ./test.sh -e eh
./test.sh: illegal option -- e
```